# How to releas the memory allocated in for appDelegate shared instace

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my app I have created an appdelegate shared instance and the I am allocating memory to the some array like

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate_Shared *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.allServiceAppList_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.blockXMLData_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.notesXMLData_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Now I am not getting how to release the all arrays which I have allocated. it's showing potential leaks where I alloc and init the memory.

what is the correct way to release these objects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should read the documentation about memory management. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html Are you using ARC?

Answer (score 2):

If the AppDelegate properties are defined as (retain), just do

```
appDelegate.something = [[[Something alloc]init]autorelease];
```

this is the most common pattern in ObjC.

Retained properties will retain the new object, the autorelease essentially releases the object in the future, so the end result is an object with a retain count of 1 which will be released in a dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

don't do like that

use this way

```
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.allServiceAppList_array = arr;
[arr release];
arr =nil;

arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.blockXMLData_array = arr;
[arr release];
arr =nil;

arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.notesXMLData_array = arr;
[arr release];
arr =nil;
```

Comment: thanks, but can I release the arrays as I have allocated in the above way? I like your way.

Comment: the allocated array's pointers have been assigned to delegates array, and you are releasing the one in your scope

Comment: @user1398312 Please make sure you read and understand Objective-C's memory management (see the link I added in the comment). Don't just blindly copy and paste code as this will cause problems - take the time to understand it. Note that this answer will cause lots of problems if you are using ARC.

Comment: @NickBull i think you have not read his question. he has asked how to release that objects, so definitely there is MRC if you have some common sense

Comment: @TheSaad If you have some "Common sense" then you would realise I was pointing out that if the OP doesn't understand what is going on and later switches to use ARC, then there will be problems. This is why I suggested to the OP that they should take the time to learn and understand what is going on.